# For an integer $n\geq2$, we define the set $E=\left\{\frac{p}{q} : p,q \in \mathbb{N}, p+q=n\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

For an integer $n\geq2$, we define the set $E=\left\{\frac{p}{q} : p,q \in \mathbb{N}, p+q=n\right\}$

Show that this set is bounded, and determine $\sup E$ and $\inf E$.

By developing some elements of the set, I was able to notice that $\inf E = \frac{1}{n-1}$ and $\sup E=n-1$.

But I'm not even sure how the proof goes on....

Answer (score 1):

$E$ is a nonempty finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and it is well known that such a subset has a smallest and a largest element.

Of course, this is not true for any infinite subset. Consider for example the interval $(0,1)$, which has no smallest and no largest element. It has nevertheless a "largest lower bound" = 0 and a "smallest upper bound" = 1.

Now, let's go back to :

$$E=\{\frac{n}{q}-1;\,1\le q\le n\}$$

The smallest element of $E$ is reached by choosing the largest value of $q$; and the largest element of $E$ is reached by choosing the smallest value of $q$. So we have :

$$\inf(E)=\min(E)=0\qquad\mathrm{and}\qquad\sup(E)=\max(E)=n-1$$

**Note** : I consider that $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of *all* natural numbers, including $0$. If you consider that $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of *positive* integers (1, 2, etc ...) then you have to adapt slightly what I wrote :

$$E=\{\frac{n}{q}-1;\,1\le q\le n-1\}$$

and the conclusion becomes :

$$\inf(E)=\min(E)=\frac{1}{n-1}\qquad\mathrm{and}\qquad\sup(E)=\max(E)=n-1$$

Comment: Um, no, it's not possible for $\frac{p}{q}=-1$ if $p,q\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: (i) $\frac{n}{n}-1$ is not $-1$; (ii) you need $q<n$, not $q\le n$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrew, ans TonyK - Of course, sorry. Editing the typo

Comment: Can you reformulate ? This doesn't give me anymore understanding to be honest. Details would be preferable.Thanks

Comment: @copper - Ok, Trying to do so ...

Comment: You lost me when writing inf / sup. Why 0 as the inf ? Why n-1 as the sup ?

Comment: @copper - You probably should look at a some course material; maybe here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_and_lower_bounds